# What is "endmail.mc.swpivert(-1)"?

Tags: centos, sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I recently noticed that a sendmail server had the following at the top of the /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file:

```
endmail.mc.swpivert(-1)
```

This was breaking sendmail restarts so I changed it back to the default of `divert(-1)`

I'm 95% certain that this is just user error but as I don't explicitly manage the system in question, I don't want to make assumptions and wanted to double-check. Is swpivert(-1) a valid entry?  What are acceptable values for the top of the sendmail.mc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an editing error where a line containing "sendmail.mc" was mangled with the first line which most probably was `divert(-1)`

It looks like while someone was in vi command (escape) mode, right after `vi sendmail.mc`, pasted the word "sendmail.mc" with the cursor on the top left position (over the letter `d`). Try it in a dummy file and you will get a similar result.

The .swp part shows that it was pasted from a vim backup file.

Comment: This is exactly what happened, only the pasted text would have been `.sendmail.mc.swp`.